# Angular custom element, getting element not found error

Tags: angular-elements

I'm writing an angular custom element.  Rather than explaining the whole thing I have uploaded the code to the following url

https://github.com/arjunagl/angular-custom-elememtns

However when I add the code to a standard html page like the following

Hello World, this is where the custom element should come

I get the following error `The selector "app-contact-form" did not match any elements`. Seems like its still trying to search by the actual name of the component rather than the name I registered it by `customElements.define('my-contact-form', el);`. Furthermore even if I change the registration name to the same name `app-contact-form` I get the same error

This is the command I run to generate the output `ng build --prod --output-hashing none` and next I run `npm run concat` to generate the output file.

Comment: Same problem.  Did you ever figure this out?  It's like it uses the internal name.  In my case I'm trying to export one component as a custom element from a sub-project.  I feel like it must be some problem with my module.

Comment: Nevermind.  My issue was ultimately something else that broke when I moved my component to a sub-project.  I should have tested the sub-project first before trying to make one of its components a custom element.